# Stop timer in TimeCircles

Tags: javascript, jquery, time

In TimeCircles, in the example "Time since page was opened" in url "http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Attractive-jQuery-Circular-Countdown-Timer-Plugin-TimeCircles/", which is the normal counting the timer. How do I do it to stop time (eg 15 seconds)? And when i click start it back counting where time has stopped (the 15 seconds and not 20 seconds if I stayed with the pause time 5 seconds)

Answer (score 0):

When you give neither data-date or data-timer, TimeCircles will take the current "Date" (DateTime) as a reference point. You can
t prevent the actual time from moving away from a static datetime value. Instead, you should use `data-timer="0"`, this will cause TimeCircles to count instead and allows you to pause and unpause the timer without the time jumping ahead.